# Cingulate cortex vs Limbic lobe are they same or slightly different?

Tags: terminology, brain, neuroanatomy, definition

I've read the wikipedia article on Cingulate cortex and the article about limbic lobe. Also did web search but it is not clear to me whether they are synonymous or there are slight differences in the parts they include.

**UPDATE:**

it seems search terms for "limbic system" and "limbic lobe" giving me a different google search result. There also are wikipedia pages on

[1. Cingulate cortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cingulate_cortex),
[2. Limbic Lobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbic_lobe) ,
[3. Limbic System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbic_system) .

where cingulate cortex (1) is confusingly similar to Limbic lobe (2) but Limbic system (3) seem to be different (but inclusive) terminology from limbic lobe (2).

So I want to know if limbic "lobe" and cingulate cortex are synonymous or they differ in the areas they include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer: 
The limbic lobe (aka limbic cortex) is made up of the cingulate gyrus and the parahippocampal gyrus (so the cingulate gyrus is only part of the limbic lobe). The limbic lobe is part of the limbic system. There is some disagreement over what the limbic system includes, but some of the other areas contained in the limbic system include the subcallosal gyrus, hippocampus, and amygdala.

Comment: If it helps, I use a combination of sources whenever I'm learning about an area. The Human Brain Coloring Book (Collins), Radiopedia.org, and KenHub.com (I just use the free version that you get by registering) are the ones I use the most. It's risky to rely on just one because there are inconsistencies. I only use Wikipedia as a very last resort because it contains far too many errors and too much information, making it hard to understand. I'm sure there are better resources out there so if anyone else has any suggestions, I'd be very keen to hear them.

Comment: Wikipedia isn't a great place to learn about neuroanatomy. It is often confusing and misleading. See suggestions for alternatives in the previous comment.

Comment: Human brain colouring book??? Seems SOOO exciting, I'll purchase one whenever it will be possible. I just love to learn through pictures and sketches and usually i cannot memorise info about something until and unless i can associate it with distinctive shapes or picture cards.

Comment: It's a great book. It contains detailed text as well as diagrams to color. https://www.amazon.com/dp/0064603067/